# Ruby game development for Web

Tags: ruby, game-engine

I would like to develop web games using Ruby, but I can't find any framework for that. Can I use Gosu to create the game and then just compile it to js (with Opal, for example)?

Comment: you can use a web framework such as ruby on rails

Comment: I didnt find any information about how to write games with ruby on rails. Can u give me links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two libraries for writing browser games with Ruby:

[dare](https://github.com/domgetter/dare)

[yeah](https://github.com/yeahrb/yeah)

FYI, I don't think Opal is quite so advanced that you can compile absolutely *anything* into Javascript. 
If you're going to be using Opal, you should probably test Javascript compilation as you build.

Comment: I think that their functional is limited compared Gosu. Isn't it? Can I write missing classes that will working with other dare/yeah core? Thank you.

Comment: I have no idea. I just searched google. Haven't used any myself.